Difference in validation result using `jsonschema` and `check-jsonschema` in regard to a field with value of date-time
Given model_schema.json
{
  "properties": {
    "dt": {
      "format": "date-time",
      "title": "Dt",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "dt"
  ],
  "title": "Model",
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"
}

and model_instance.json
{
  "dt": "2032-04-23T10:20:30"
}

Running the following Python script produces no error.
import json
from pprint import pprint

import jsonschema


with open("model_schema.json") as f:
    schema = json.load(f)

with open("model_instance.json") as f:
    m1_as_dict = json.load(f)


pprint(schema)
print("\n=====================================\n")
pprint(m1_as_dict)


jsonschema.validate(m1_as_dict, schema)

However, running the the following command
check-jsonschema --schemafile model_schema.json model_instance.json

produces the following error
Schema validation errors were encountered.
  model_instance.json::$.dt: '2032-04-23T10:20:30' is not a 'date-time'

I think the command's behavior is correct. Why doesn't the given Python script produce a comparable error as the command?
My environment is:
check-jsonschema          0.28.2
jsonschema                4.21.1
jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1
types-jsonschema          4.21.0.20240331


Per the specifications (literally all releases of the JSON Schema spec) format does not validate.  It is informative only (in later versions it "produces an annotation").  An implementation MAY elect to validate format, however that functionality SHOULD be disabled unless explicitly configured.
(All format validation tests are listed as optional in the official JSON Schema Test Suite for this reason.)
The date-time, date, and time formats are all specified to indicate an RFC3339 format, which your value doesn't meet.
So... both are working fine, but the python is working more correctly because it's not validating format.
I recommend taking this back to the CLI tool and telling them to hide format validation behind a configuration.

According to the documentation, no format validation is done if no format checker is provided for the validation. When calling jsonschema.validate, pass a keyword argument of format_checker, so that the created validator as the result of the call will a format checker and will do format validation.
I.e.,
Replace the line
jsonschema.validate(m1_as_dict, schema)

with
jsonschema.validate(m1_as_dict, schema, format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker())

